# Non-standard go module publishing

Tags: go, release, versioning

I'm trying to publish a new Go library (on a github repo I'm contributing to), however I'm struggling to figure out how best to handle publishing/versioning it, as some things are a little non-standard.

It's a multi-language repo, essentially providing the same SDK in different languages (so far python/ts, and soon to be Go). Because of this, we have the following directory structure:

```
py:
    ...python-SDK
ts:
    ...ts-SDK
go: (what I'm currently working on)
    go.mod
    sdk.go
```

And the following tag formats:

- py-vX.X.X
- ts-vX.X.X
- go-vX.X.X (Ideally what we'd have)

I'm looking for a way to:

a) publish this so that ideally (but not necessarily) when `go get`ing the SDK it shows the version number correctly (with or without prefix) in `go.mod`.

b) publish the documentation correctly to [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/)

Is this possible with the above directory layout/tag formatting? If not, what alternatives could I go with? If I need to change the tagging/directory structure/etc I'll need to convince the repo maintainers of the reasons.

Contents of the `go.mod` file:

```
module github.com/example/newrepo/go

go 1.20
```

github tag: go-v0.0.1

running `go get github.com/example/newrepo/go@go-v0.0.1` in a separate project downloads the correct version, however leads to something like this in the external project's `go.mod` file:

```
require github.com/jamesL92/versiontest/go v0.0.0-20230822004615-1c9a4a58d350
```

(note it's showing `v0.0.0-...` instead of `v0.0.1-...` or `go-v0.0.1-...`)

I've also tried running `GOPROXY=proxy.golang.org go list -m github.com/go/jamesL92/versiontest/go@go-v0.0.1` however this results in the following error:

```
go: github.com/go/jamesL92/versiontest/go@go-v0.0.1: invalid version: reading https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/go/james%21l92/versiontest/go/@v/go-v0.0.1.info: 404 Not Found
        server response:
        not found: github.com/go/jamesL92/versiontest/go@go-v0.0.1: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/c3a61b6784b0247e9d86d0359bef434efe5151f32d1486ed6d997a4fe46a603e: exit status 128:
                fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
        Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
        If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

(N.B this is a public repo).